# Hot reload make my app logout Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working on an e-commerce app. I made all its authentication and storing using Firebase. To enter the app I have to make and account and sign in. While signing in, when I make any change in my code and try to save it using CTRL+s or hot reload the app sign out and I get back to the login screen again!!

I don't get the problem at all !! I don't even know which code should I add with my question !!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Without that, it's unlikelty we'll do better than the docs here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage

Answer (score 2):

Verify if you create de initialize var inside build in main, the correct is create outside build like this:

```
class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
final Future<FirebaseApp> _init = Firebase.initializeApp();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _init,
  ...
  )
}
```

Comment: I have it this way and still get logged out when doing a hot reload (sign in method with email & password)